# AngularJS ng-src and absolute URL's

Tags: html, angularjs, src

I'm currently running a gallery app using ng-src to read in URL's. I'm receiving another website's image URL's, and I was wondering if ng-src could receive absolute URL's like `http://thiswebsite.com/image/1`

Currently, it's only routing relative, so I get `http://mywebsite.com/http://thiswebsite.com/image/1`

Comment: [All indications are this should be working](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/LLcxke5L/) -- can you post an example of what you're doing?

Comment: can you post an example at http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: look here: http://jsbin.com/wefis/1/edit

Comment: Sorry, I realized my mistake. It wasn't an ng-src issue I don't think... But i'll keep this question up until I know for sure

Comment: unless I don't get it, `http://mywebsite.com/http://thiswebsite.com/image/1` doesn't seems like an image url. Maybe you are not getting an image, but a document...

Comment: Hi, the problem here was the URL itself. The image which you were trying to access was probably removed by the owner and thus, you were getting a 404 not found in response which is an HTML. An ng-src can only have an image as a response for it to properly work. I made some changes to your bin and it's working. http://jsbin.com/wefis/1/edit?html,js,output